# When to capitalize a job title

Tags: capitalization

I'm currently writing a blog about web development. I'm unsure of when to capitalize a job title and the industry.

Are the following sentences correct?

As an experienced Front-End Developer......

Having worked alongside other developers....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

I would change the first sentence to lower case and leave the second as is.

**Longer Answer**

I think this is up to your personal preference.  When you are advertising yourself, or putting your career on your bio or business card, I would capitalize it.  If, on the other hand, you were writing a story about "Joe, the **front-end developer**", I would not capitalize it, just like you wouldn't capitalize "Joe, the **teacher**".

As for your second example, I would never capitalize the word "developers" unless it were at the beginning of a sentence, or title text.